# Display AutoCAD drawing with True scale

Tags: scale, autocad

I am trying to view a Wiring diagram with True scale in a 65-inch display. With the help of view11 add-on file for AutoCAD, I am able to set the drawing to 1:1 scale relative to the display size. But it maintains the scale only in the AutoCAD application. I want to save the drawing as a view-only file while maintaining its true scale. Taking the screenshot will maintain the scale but it will also include all the toolbars and taskbars which I do not want. Is there any alternative method to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is the province of draughting [drafting] expertise, and once we're looking at display scale issues with CAD, we're far outside graphic design.

Comment: print it as PDF

Answer (score 2):

There is generally no way to ensure a thing shows up at same scale on another computer. There are several reasons for this. But basically reasons are as follows:

1. Its not your computer.

   You simply can never completely override local user. If local user wants zoom it zooms.
2. The size of the screen may not be known by the computer.

   For example screen is projected on a wall, or screen is copied on multiple different sized screens
3. Users screen may be unsuitable for the task that you think they should be doing

So all you can really do is ask the user to view it at 1:1 scale. You may need to write instructions as to how to do this. On the other hand your really fighting windmills here as you will have a failure at some point.

**PS**: Taking screenshot will not maintain scale. This is only true if they have same monitor as you and their viewing application maxes the image. Which is a bit unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of CAD viewers available for Windows and Mac OS, and I believe several for Linux too... all will allow view scale control. DWG True View is one published by AutoDesk themselves, and works pretty well for all that.

However, although I'm all about digital content delivery in the AEC field (really, I'm a BIM guy so I'd rather deliver a model any day versus rolls and rolls of drawings) in this case, I'd say the simplest, straight-ahead answer is to correctly plot to scale into printed output - at the required 1:1 scale, and refer to the drawing physically.

Whichever method you choose - good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea. I do not know your add on, but you could try "printing" your selected area as PDF.